# Ansible When statement (IF else)

Tags: ansible

I just started learning about ansible. I wonder how do I do an IF ELSE Statement in ansible. I know that ansible use when for their If statement. Therefore here is a bunch of code of me trying to use when. The objective here is for me to check if the value of priv is "privilege". This code is working but I think there something wrong with the when statement. The output is always returning me false even when there are suppose to have a true outcome. Anyone knows where it goes wrong? Thanks. :)

[The code look like. Easier to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE37O.png)

> - name: User | Username    set_fact:
>   user_username: "{{ item.split(' ')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE37O.png) }}"
>   cacheable: yes   with_items: "{{ output12 }}"
> - name: check priv   set_fact:
>   priv: "{{ item.split(' ')[2] }}"   with_items: "{{ output12 }}"   register: priv
> - name: check    set_fact:
>   is_privilege: false
>   when: priv != "privilege"   with_items: "{{output12}}"
> - name: check 2   set_fact:
>   is_privilege: true
>   when: priv == "privilege"   with_items: "{{output12}}"

Comment: You're doing it in a loop, so it ends up with the value from the last line

Comment: any idea/tips/tricks for me to check line by line?

Comment: Hi Hary Aprianto Ginting welcome to SO. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69564543/edit) and fix the formatting, since it is currently unreadable and with yaml the whitespace matters a great deal. Good luck.

Comment: One way is to use a combination of filters in Jinja, then checking whether the result has at least one item

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to read with the way the question loses the formatting; would you be able to edit it and fix the formatting?

---

One way is to use a combination of filters in Jinja, then checking whether the result has at least one item, like this:

```
- name: check privilege
  set_fact:
    is_privilege: >-
      {{
        output3.stdout[0].split('\n')
        | select('eq', priv)
        | list | length > 0
      }}
```

BTW, when displaying a variable with debug, it's better to use `var` rather than `msg`; this will format up the value better, for instance letting you see if there are stray spaces:

```
- debug: 
    var: priv
```

You can use the same form to debug Jinja expressions; this will format the result up neatly as data structures, so you can quickly experiment with the filters:

```
- debug: 
    var: >-
        output3.stdout[0].split('\n')
        | select('eq', priv)
        | list | length > 0
```

Comment: hi mate, I have put a picture to see the code. I've tried editing it but it keep going back to this format. Thanks

Comment: Use three backticks above the code section...